# XCTest force touch automation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automated-tests, xctest

We just implemented force touch in to our app where user can access few of the app features directly through force touch pop up. So just wondering whether XCTest in Xcode support force touch automation [Something similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYVR5.png). So what I'm trying to do is forceTap on the our app icon and make the test to tap one of the options as shown linked image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: was trying to use different methods like: touch and hold with duration, still same, unable to get to the 3D touch menu, only thing was able to get is a dancing icons when you can delete icons, seems that 3D touch aka force touch using a hardware to detect your hard touch =)